# How to change the domain from example.com to example.com/homepage/

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudflare, namecheap

I have purchased a domain name from Namecheap and it is as follows : example.com , and I use each of the following services: 1 - My hosting is from Digital Ocean. 2 - I use Cloudflare as a CDN. Now where and how do I modify the domain to be as follows:example.com/homepage/ in the previous services.thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This is your domain: `example.com`. This is just a path on your web server: `/homepage/`. The `/homepage/` path is totally handled by the webserver. Your domain name service (DNS) does not handle that path at all.

You would need to configure your webserver on Digital Ocean to actually have a web page hosted at the `/homepage/` path. Then you could configure your web server to redirect all requests to the root path `/` to `/homepage/`.